# Запуск Android Studio в virtual box в windows 10

Tags: android-studio, virtualbox

Не работает Android Studio на виртуалке, в девайс менеджер пишет что не установлен HAXM, но его не получается установить, процессор i7 6 поколения u

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: проверьте что в виртулке установлена поддержка виртуализации